# Explain the difference between CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat)) and CreateCriteria<Cat>()

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, createcriteria

I've seen both formats in different examples, tutorials, blogs, etc, but for the life of me, I cannot find an explanation for the difference. What is the difference between

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat));
```

and

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria<Cat>();
```

When do I use one and when do I use the other?

An example of a tutorial using session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat)) can be found at http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart

An example of a tutorial using session.CreateCriteria() can be found at http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples (table Blog instead of Cat)

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no** difference. You can/should use the generic one if possible, and non-generic if you have access only to a Type instance (some reflection).

The non-generic is part of NHibernate from the moment when it was imported from Java `Hibernate`.

The generic was added in the *`Build 2.1.0.Alpha1`* release.

But because the result is *non-generic* `ICriteria`  (in comparison with result of the `QueryOver<T>()`) it is just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, which one is the generic one? (I know this sounds like a stupid question, but the documentation I found, http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html, does not explain it.)

Comment: generic is the `session.CreateCriteria<Cat>();` this should be used if possible